# How to get group of fields with all results, less than all etc

Tags: php, mysql, sql, grouping

I need to contruct a query, from keywords entered by a user in a text-field, which will do the following: Take the keywords and search in a table, after which car has all the given keywords, less than all and continuing down the car which has just one keyword.
My table looks like this:

```
field_id | car_id | keyword |
----------------------------
1        | 5       | 1989   |
-----------------------------
2        | 8       | old    |
-----------------------------
3        | 8       | ford   |
-----------------------------
6        | 8       | cheap  |
-----------------------------
4        | 7       | ford   |
-----------------------------
6        | 7       | cheap  |
-----------------------------
5        | 6       | ford   |
-----------------------------
```

Say if the user searched for "old", "ford" and "cheap", car_id 8, 7 and 6 should be returned because they contains the keywords. Furthermore I need to know which car has which keywords (8: "old", "ford", "cheap" And 7: "ford", "cheap" And 6: "ford") . Im not an expert with MySQL so I don't now if it is possible to create some sort of multidimensional array here...

I have a query which select only the car which has all the keywords entered, if it is of any use:

```
Select car_id from keywords 
Where keyword in ("old","ford", "cheap") 
group by car_id having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really see how that question is related to mine:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need having because it will only send whenever there exist only 3 cars belongs to given keywords. Try this

```
Select car_id from keywords ,,GROUP_CONCAT(keyword)
Where keyword in ("old","ford", "cheap") 
group by car_id
```

This will give you comma separated keywords that belongs to car

Comment: that would just return all cars which have either                 "old" OR/AND "ford" OR/AND "cheap" and group them by car_id. But this doesn't tell me which car has which keywords.

Comment: The output should be the same as what you get if you use the query you provided, but there has to be some way to know which car_id has which keywords. It should be like a multidimensional array where the car_id is the key and all the keywords matching that car_id are the content of the sub-array

Comment: updated by answer. this will give you comma separated keywords belongs to this car_id, you can make it array by explode in php. hope this will work

Comment: You should add the clause "order by count(*) desc" to get the results in the order you want.